# Transpose of column to row in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a problem in transposing column to rows,

Here is the sample data pattern having  number of column:

```
gender | Maths | English | science
----------------------------------
Male   | 20    | 89      | 59 
Female | 70    | 56      | 79
```

I would like to transpose it to below format

```
Subject | Male | Female
------------------------
Maths   | 20    | 70     
English | 89    | 56      
Science | 59    | 79
```

Comment: Your question sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087158/how-can-i-rotate-a-2d-array-in-php-by-90-degrees is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Consider normalising your schema (e,g. student(student_id, gender), subject (subject_id, subject_name), grade(student_id,subject_id,grade)

Answer (score 0):

We can try a union approach combined with a pivot query here:

```sql
SELECT
    Subject,
    MAX(CASE WHEN gender = 'Male'   THEN score END) AS Male,
    MAX(CASE WHEN gender = 'Female' THEN score END) AS Female
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Maths' AS Subject, gender, Maths AS score FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'English', gender, English FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'science', gender, science FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY
    Subject;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo